# Insert image in database using faker library

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

**Factory Class**

```
$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'image' => url("/images/{$faker->image('public/storage/images',640,480, null, false)}")
    ];
});
```

And after this command

```
php artisan db:seed
```

image column of database filled with this string

```
http://localhost/images/a1af4cb757aef7f6b181dfb978228767.jpg"
```

***and when i seach this url on browser, i get "Unable to connect" error***

Comment: you need to add `storage` before `images/imageName` to be like this `http://localhost/storage/images/a1af4cb757aef7f6b181dfb978228767.jpg`

Comment: but make sure that you run the command `php artisan storage:link` before run the seeding command

Comment: thanks sir , now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `storage` in your link before `images/image_name` to be like this

```
http://localhost/storage/images/a1af4cb757aef7f6b181dfb978228767.jpg
```

> Make sure that you run `php artisan storage:link`